# How many epochs should Word2Vec be trained? What is a recommended training dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

I am learning about Word2Vec using the TensorFlow tutorial.  The code I am running for Word2Vec is also from the TensorFlow tutorial:  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec_optimized.py .  When I ran the code for 15 epochs, the test accuracy was around 30%.  When I ran for 100 epochs, test accuracy got up to around 39%.  I am using the Text8 dataset for training and questions-words.txt for evaluation.

Do I need to run for more epochs?  Should I be using a different dataset?  How can I improve test accuracy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Larger datasets are better; `text8` is very, very small – sufficient for showing some of the analogy-solving power of word-vectors, but not good enough for other purposes.

More iterations may help squeeze slightly stronger vectors out of smaller datasets, but with diminishing returns. (No number of extra iterations over a weak dataset can extract the same rich interrelationships that a larger, more varied corpus can provide.)

There's a related `text9` from the same source that if I recall correctly, is 10x larger. You'll likely get better evaluation results from using it, than from doing 10x more iterations on `text8`.

I believe the 3 million pretrained vectors Google once released – the `GoogleNews` set – were trained on a corpus of 100 billion words' worth of news articles, but with just 3 passes.

Note that there's no single standard for word-vector quality: the `questions-words.txt` analogy solving is just one convenient evaluation, but it's possible the word-vectors best at that won't be best at your own domain-specific analyses. Similarly, word-vectors trained on one domain of text, like the `GoogleNews` set from news articles, might underperform compared to text that better matches your domain (like perhaps forum posts, scientific articles, etc. – which all use different words in different ways).

So it's often best to use your own corpus, and your own goal-specific quantitative evaluation, to help adjust corpus/parameter choices.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try a larger dataset.

Comment: The larger dataset did increase test accuracy.  Thanks also for the recommendation to match dataset and tests to the subject material.